# Getting properties of Button inside UniformGrid C#

Tags: c#

I was wondering if it is possible for me to get the properties of a Button that is a child of a UniformGrid using a UniformGrid click event instead of a Button click event. The UniformGrid is created with XAML and the Button is created in C#. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it's possible.

A clean way to do it would be to bind the button properties you want to access to your ViewModel and then from the command raised on the click event within your UniformGrid, well, access those properties.

Since [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx) works on XAML and CodeBehind it works independently from where you create the objects.